# OpenRC How to delay service startup?

Tags: linux, boot, gentoo

I tried looking for a way to delay a service in startup because it slows down starting.  I want to delay Dhcpc startup, because its probing IP too long. So I want to delay it after logging in, but I couldn't find anything in [OpenRC gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/OpenRC).

I have been using `systemd` my whole life so OpenRC is totally new to me.  I just know how to add a service or remove it but I have no idea about delaying.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, dhcpd, what you want to do is edit **/etc/conf.d/dhcpd**, uncomment the last line and modify it to read `DHCPD_OPTS="-b"`. This should background the service immediately, and let boot go on. I've not tested this for compatibility with other services that expect an address, but it should accomplish what you want.

Comment: This could affect services that have a net dependency.  I would recommend updating openRC to start processes in parallel to speed up boot.  the key value is RC_PARALLEL="yes"